# Access linked object in Twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine, lazy-loading

Currently working on a Symfony2 application and I'm having some troubles with the lazy loading of objects.

I currently get all my matches with

```
$matches = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Matchgame')
        ->findByTournament($tournament);
```

All of the matches consist of a few details, like roundnumber and stuff and also holds the participants. These participants are from a ManyToOne relation.

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     */
    private $participant1;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     */
    private $participant2;
```

When I pass the $matches variable to my Twig template

```
  {% for match in matches %}
      <p>{{ match.participant1.username }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
```

and then try to access the username, I get the error

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a null variable in tournament/single.html.twig at line 46
```

Like I said, this is probably because of the lazy loading. But is there any workaround for this? In other words, can I tell Doctrine to fully load the request?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", fetch="EAGER")
 */
```